# didSelectItemAt indexPath called after a long press

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used collectionview and set the imageview in collection view cell. i need to move another viewcontroller after the cell was touched. But my problem is the view moves after a long press on cell in collection view.
This is my code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let imagesPath = documentPath.appendingPathComponent(reportImageFolder)
    let cell = arrImagesFiltered[indexPath.item]
    let imageNameWithPath = "\(imagesPath)/\(cell)"
    let imageEditViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EditImageViewController") as! EditImageViewController
    imageEditViewController.imagePath = imageNameWithPath
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageEditViewController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: did you use any gestureRecognizers?

Comment: May be Added **TapGestureRecognizer** somewhere and it prevents selection of **cell**

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on the first line in the function and then step through line by line to find out where the delay is. It's also possible the issue is in the new view controller and some expensive operation that is slowing ti down. In the new view set a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and step through the code in viewDidLoad if needed to determine where it's slowing down.

Comment: no, I am not use gesturerecognizers

Comment: DIdselectItem at indexpath called after a long press on the cell.

Comment: I am using tapgestureRecognizer for keyboard.

Comment: Did you resolve this @ios as I seem to be having an identical issue and can't figure out where it's coming from!

Answer (score 0):

For future readers of this old question - *probably me in the future* ;)

I had a `UITapGestureRecognizer` which was swallowing my short taps and hence only the old taps were making it through! You just need to add `tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false`!

```swift
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapDidTouch(sender:)))
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```